# How to center ionic avatar on a page

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to `center` the **avatar** to the middle, with the code below but it doesn't work. 
I have used this `class="ion-align-items-center"` that i got from the **ionic documents** but with no successs.

```
    <ion-grid style ="text-align: center">
     <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center" >

    <ion-col class="ion-align-items-center" *ngFor="let item of students" >
      <!--   <div  class= "imageHold" >
            <ion-img [src]= "profileImage || item.profileImage"></ion-img>
        </div> -->
        <ion-avatar class="ion-align-items-center">
            <ion-img [src]= "profileImage || item.profileImage"></ion-img>
          </ion-avatar>
    </ion-col>  
   </ion-row >
   <ion-row  style ="text-align: center">  
       <ion-col>
    <ion-button  size="small" fill="outline" (click)="chooseProfilePic()" >Choose Profile Photo</ion-button>
   </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
```

I get this result

[image]

Comment: `align-items-center` is for *vertical* centering. You may want `justify-content-center`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a class in the avatar div.

```
.avatar{
   margin: auto;
}
```